# coding numbers into letters With HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I am looking for a way to code numbers into letters. I want to take an inputted django variable and flip the numbers to letters using the following:

```
1=M
2=A
3=k
4=E
etc.
```

What is the best way to complete this? I have looked at the switch function, but I can only seem to get it to work for 1 character. How would I get it to switch each number outputted from a Django variable?

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
       function myFunction() {
      var text;
      var Number = {{ Label.MetaData.price|number_format(0, '', '')|raw }};
      switch(Number) {
        case "1": text = "M"; break;
        case "2": text = "A"; break;
        case "3": text = "K"; break;
        case "4": text = "E"; break;
        }
        document.getElementById("code").innerHTML = text; }
    </script>
    <p id="code"></p>
```

Comment: Sounds like you need some sort of loop and loop over each number and output the letter. Hard to guess what `witch each number outputted from a Django variable` means exactly

Answer (score 1):

Using an object is probably the easiest way. Here's an example.

```js
const letterMap = {
  " ": 0,
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4,
  e: 5,
  f: 6,
  g: 7,
  h: 8,
  i: 9,
  j: 10,
  k: 11,
  l: 12,
  m: 13,
  n: 14,
  o: 15,
  p: 16,
  q: 17,
  r: 18,
  s: 19,
  t: 20,
  u: 21,
  v: 22,
  w: 23,
  x: 24,
  y: 25,
  z: 26,
}

const sentence = "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"
for (const char of sentence) console.log(letterMap[char]);
```

Comment: Pardon intrusion, since it basically is an unassociative array, wouldn't it be better to just utilize the array methods (indexOf to begin with)?

Comment: @entio That would work too, but accessing the value using a key is a lot faster. Also, you can choose the values of the letters, unlike with an array.

Comment: Well I kinda tend to think that the performance gains are negligible in this particular case. And with array you can set the index of a letter too. But well, You've got your point. If the indexes are not continuous, than all the benefits are lost.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Replaced single quotes.

```
const characterString = 'MAKE';

const myNumber = 2  // replace with yours

const myLetter = characterString.charAt(myNumber);  // K
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt